# Setinterval for div in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, image

This is my jquery prg. I have fully worked this and animate the image properly. Here first image animate 2 second and stoped and second image continue the animation. after fourth image animated  I need to start first image animation. I want to call `anim()` function in infinite times. please help me

My Script is in jquery contains four functions showFirst,showSecond,showThird,showfour

This is the anim function to call the four function in time interval

```
$(function anim() {

    $('div.f:not(:first)').hide(); // Hide all columns except the first
    $('div.s:not(:first)').hide(); // Hide all columns except the first
    $('div.c:not(:first)').hide(); // Hide all columns except the first
    $('div.d:not(:first)').hide(); // Hide all columns except the first
    // showFirst();

    var timesRun = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        timesRun += 1;
        if(timesRun === 2){
            clearInterval(interval);

            var timesRun1= 0;
            var interval1 = setInterval(function(){
            timesRun1 += 1;
            if(timesRun1 === 2){
                clearInterval(interval1);

                var timesRun2 = 0;
                var interval2 = setInterval(function(){
                    timesRun2 += 1;
                    if(timesRun2 === 2){
                        clearInterval(interval2);
                        var timesRun3 = 0;
                        var interval3 = setInterval(function(){
                            timesRun3 += 1;
                            if(timesRun3 === 2){
                                clearInterval(interval3);
                            }
                            showFour();
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                    showSecond();   
                },1000); 
            }
            showThird();
        }, 1000); }showFirst();
    }, 1000);       
});
```

I have four images with four alternate images. i changed the images in 2 sec time interval. i write this code in anim function. Now i call inside the function in anim. But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `anim()` again when the rest of your animations finish

```
     if(timesRun3 === 2){
          clearInterval(interval3);
          anim();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe are you looking for something like this?

```js
var current = 0;
var i1 = 'http://jsfiddle.net/img/top-bg.png';
var i2 = 'http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png';

function anim() {
    if (++current > 4) {
        current = 1;
    }
    var div = $('#wrap div').eq(current);
    div.animate({
        height: '0px' // this can be also set to fixed size
    }, 2000, function() {
        var img = $(this).children('img')[0];
        img.src = img.src == i1 ? i2 : i1;
        $(this).animate({
            height: '100px'
        }, 2000, function() {
            anim();
        });
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wrap img').prop('src', i1);
    anim();
});
```

@ [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tGfvb/1/)